# Does Darboux theorem imply that $f'$ cannot have jump discontinuity?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Does the Darboux theorem for derivatives imply that a derivative on a interval $I$ cannot have jump discontinuity?

Darboux theorem states that the derivative function follow the intermediate value theorem on a interval $I$.

My doubts are about a function like this

$f(x)=\begin{cases} x-1, 0\leq x\leq 2\\ x+1, -2\leq x < 0\end{cases}$

It has a jump discontinuity nevertheless it seems to follow the intermediate value theorem

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help

Comment: @user Absolutely true. I'll retract that (doh). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $f$ doesn't satisfy intermediate value theorem. We have $f(-0.5)=0.5,f(0.5)=-0.5$, so intermediate value theorem (if it held in this case) would tell us that there is a number $\alpha$ between $-0.5$ and $0.5$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$, since $0$ is between $f(-0.5)$ and $f(0.5)$, but this isn't true.

Comment: I think you mean $f(0.5)=-0.5$.

Comment: @kccu Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is not a derivative. (!) Precisely, there exists no differentiable function $F$ on $[-2, 2]$ satisfying $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $[-2, 2]$. (The problematic point is $x = 0$.)